# Find the function $f(x)$ by using its fourier expansion

Tags: series-expansion, fourier-analysis

It is easy to find the fourier coefficient and fourier expansion of $f(x)$ function.

But I want solve the inverse problem by using *Mathematica*

How to find the function $f(x)$, if I know  its fourier coefficient (or fourier expantion)?

for example:

$$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi^2n^2}$$

$$b_n=0$$

$$a_0=\frac{1}{6}$$
 or

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{6}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos2xn\pi}{(n\pi)^2}$$

I tried:

```
Simplify[1/6 - Sum[Cos[2 x Pi n]/(Pi n)^2, {n, 1, Infinity}]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[%, {x, -3, 3},PlotRange -> 1]
```

[image]

this is a fourier series of  $f(x)=x(1-x).$ with $0 \leq x \leq 1$

but how can I get  $x(1-x)$ from $\frac{1}{6}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos2xn\pi}{(n\pi)^2}$?

or in other word,

How to solve the system of integral equations for $f(x)$ by using *Mathematica*?

$$
\begin{cases}
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=conts.\\
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\sin(n x)dx=A(n)\\
\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\cos(n x)dx=B(n)
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 16):

Note that the expression returned by `Sum` is correct and equals $x(1-x)$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

I assume your question is how to simplify the expression into $x(1-x)$?

I was able to hack a solution, and unfortunately I don't think it scales very well to other expressions. But here goes:

First, evaluate the sum:

```
sum = 1/6 - Sum[Cos[2 x Pi n]/(Pi n)^2, {n, 1, Infinity}];
```

### Non rigorous approach

If you don't care about complete rigor and abuse some mathematical rules, we can get your answer very easily:

```
PowerExpand[FunctionExpand[sum]]
```

> ```
> 1 - (1 - x)^2 - x
> ```

### Rigorous approach

If you want to be 100% sure things are correct, you need to give `PowerExpand` your assumptions:

```
rigor = PowerExpand[FunctionExpand[sum], Assumptions -> 0 < x < 1]
```

[image]

Here's where *Mathematica* starts to have a hard time and we need to explicitly tell it what to do.

Seeing all the `Floor[]`, maybe we should express it as a piecewise function, and simplify each part separately. This will hopefully get rid of them:

```
rigor = FullSimplify[PiecewiseExpand[rigor, 0 < x < 1]]
```

[image]

Now, we see we are left with `Arg`. The system seems to have a hard time dealing with `Arg`, so I transform the relations in terms of `Re` and `Im`:

```
rigor = rigor /. {
 Arg[expr_] <= 0 :> (ComplexExpand[Im[expr] < 0 || Im[expr] == 0 && Re[expr] >= 0])
}
```

[image]

Finally, we want to simplify each piecewise condition with `Reduce`:

```
ReducePiecewise[expr_, x_, assum_: True] :=
  FullSimplify[
    expr /. HoldPattern[Piecewise][l_, r___] :> 
      Piecewise[Transpose[{#1, Reduce[# && assum, x]& /@ #2}& @@ Transpose[l]], r], 
    assum
  ]

ReducePiecewise[rigor, x, 0 < x < 1]
```

> ```
> -(-1 + x) x
> ```

Comment: Here's the whole business in one line: `Assuming[0 <= x <= 1, FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[FourierSequenceTransform[If[k == 0, 1/6, -(1/(2 (π k)^2))], k, x, FourierParameters -> {1, -2 π}]] // PowerExpand]]`

Comment: What do you mean by the "non rigorous" answer? That it's just of the same *form* as the original function but not equal?

Comment: No, that solution uses `PowerExpand` which uses generic identities like (a^b)^c == a^(b c) that are not always true.

Comment: Unfortunately, `PowerExpand[
 FunctionExpand[-(1/\[Pi]^3)
     I (-\[Pi]^2 Log[1 - E^(I \[Pi] x)] + \[Pi]^2 Log[
       E^(-I \[Pi] x) (-1 + E^(I \[Pi] x))] + 
     2 \[Pi]^2 Log[1 + E^(I \[Pi] x)] - 
     2 \[Pi]^2 Log[E^(-I \[Pi] x) (1 + E^(I \[Pi] x))] - 
     2 PolyLog[3, -E^(-I \[Pi] x)] + 2 PolyLog[3, E^(-I \[Pi] x)] + 
     2 PolyLog[3, -E^(I \[Pi] x)] - 2 PolyLog[3, E^(I \[Pi] x)])]]` does not work (see a more complicated case in  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/226148/sum-of-fourier-sine-series-not-giving-original-function).