# What is wrong with my approach to solving a heat transfer PDE?

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, heat-equation

I wanna solve the following heat transfer PDE using Mathematica.

$\qquad u_{xx}=u_{t}$

with following conditions:

$\qquad 
\begin{cases}u(x,0)=sin(x) &0<x<\pi &,t>0\\u_{x}(0,t)=1\\u_{x}(\pi,t)=-1\end{cases}$

I used the following codes:

```
heqn = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic = u[x, 0] == Sin[x];
bc = {Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 1, Derivative[1, 0][u][Pi, t] == -1};
sol = First @ DSolve[{heqn, ic, bc}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
sol = u[x, t] /. sol /. {K[1] -> n, Infinity -> 20}
```

But Mathematica says:

> ReplaceAll::rmix: Elements of {(u^(0,1))[x,t]==(u^(2,0))[x,t],u[x,0]==Sin[x],{(u^(1,0))[0,t]==1,(u^(1,0))[[Pi],t]==-1}} are a mixture of lists and nonlists.

Where is the problem?

Comment: use `bc = Sequence[Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 1,  Derivative[1, 0][u][Pi, t] == -1]` to fix the error indicated by the message.

Comment: @Nasser sorry i didn't understand what do you mean. Dsolve just gives the PDE in your image. Where is the solution?

Comment: @kglr No difference.

Comment: Kevin, do you still get the same error message?

Comment: @Nasser How about using numerical method?If it does not have a solution, so why when I use NDSolve and plot the results, it draws a plot? Sorry I'm not pro at this topic.

Comment: @kglr Yes the same error.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Thank You! So it means that the problem is well-posed? Would you please draw the solution with Maple so I can compare it with numerical solution of Mathematica?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this by hand to confirm Maple solution.

Since the boundary conditions are not homogeneous, we can't use separation of
variables. Let the solution  be

$$
u=v\left(  x,t\right)  +r\left(  x\right)
$$
Where $v\left(  x,t\right)  $ is the solution to $v_{t}=v_{xx}$ and homogenous
B.C. $v_{x}\left(  0,t\right)  =0,v_{x}\left(  \pi,t\right)  =0$ and $r\left(
x\right)  $ is any reference solution which only needs to satisfy the
nonhomogeneous boundary conditions: $r^{\prime}\left(  0\right)  =1,r^{\prime
}\left(  \pi\right)  =-1$. By guessing, let $r\left(  x\right)  =Ax+Bx^{2}$.
Let see if this satisfies the boundary conditions. $r^{\prime}=A+2Bx$. At
$x=0$ this implies $1=A$. Hence $r=x+Bx^{2}$. Now $r^{\prime}=1+2Bx$. At
$x=\pi$ this gives $-1=1+2B\pi$ or $B=-\frac{1}{\pi}$. Therefore
$$
r\left(  x\right)  =x-\frac{1}{\pi}x^{2}
$$
Substituting $u=v\left(  x,t\right)  +r\left(  x\right)  $ into the
PDE\ $u_{t}=u_{xx}$ and noting that $r^{\prime\prime}\left(  x\right)
=-\frac{2}{\pi}$ gives
\begin{equation}
v_{t}=v_{xx}-\frac{2}{\pi}\tag{1}
\end{equation}
PDE (1) is now solved using eigenfunction expansion. We need to find
eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of $v_{t}=v_{xx}$ with $v_{x}\left(
0,t\right)  =0,v_{x}\left(  \pi,t\right)  =0$. This is known PDE and have
eigenfunctions and eigenvalues as follows. For zero eigenvalue, the
eigenfunction is an arbitrary constant. Say $\beta$. let $\beta=1$ since scale
is not important.
$$
\Phi_{0}\left(  x\right)  =1
$$
And for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$
\begin{align*}
\Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)   &  =\cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{n}}x\right)  \\
&  =\cos\left(  nx\right)
\end{align*}
with eigenvalues $\lambda_{n}=n^{2}$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$. Now we can
eigenfunction expansion and assume the solution to (1)\ is
\begin{equation}
v\left(  x,t\right)  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi
_{n}\left(  x\right)  \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Plugging this into the PDE (1) gives
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}^{\prime\prime}\left(
x\right)  -\frac{2}{\pi}
$$
But $\Phi_{n}^{\prime\prime}\left(  x\right)  =-\lambda_{n}\Phi_{n}\left(
x\right)  $ and the above simplifies to
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)
=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}\left(  t\right)  \lambda_{n}\Phi_{n}\left(
x\right)  -\frac{2}{\pi}
$$
Since eigenfunctions are complete, we can expand $\frac{2}{\pi}$ using them
and the above becomes
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)
&  =-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}\left(  t\right)  \lambda_{n}\Phi_{n}\left(
x\right)  -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_{n}\Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)  \nonumber\\
A_{n}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  \Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)  +A_{n}\left(
t\right)  \lambda_{n}\Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)   &  =-C_{n}\Phi_{n}\left(
x\right)  \nonumber\\
A_{n}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  +A_{n}\left(  t\right)  \lambda_{n} &
=-C_{n}\tag{3}
\end{align}
To find $C_{n}$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}C_{n}\Phi_{n}\left(  x\right)  =\frac{2}{\pi}
$$
For $n=0$
$$
C_{0}\Phi_{0}\left(  x\right)  =\frac{2}{\pi}
$$
But $\Phi_{0}\left(  x\right)  =1$, hence
$$
C_{0}=\frac{2}{\pi}
$$
All other $C_{m}\,\ $\ for $m>0$ are zero. Hence (3) becomes, for $n=0$ (since
$\lambda_{0}=0$)
\begin{align*}
A_{0}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)   &  =-\frac{2}{\pi}\\
A_{0}\left(  t\right)   &  =-\frac{2}{\pi}t+B_{0}
\end{align*}
Where $B_{0}$ is integration constant. For $n>0$ (3) becomes
$$
A_{n}^{\prime}\left(  t\right)  +A_{n}\left(  t\right)  n^{2}=0
$$
This has the solution
$$
A_{n}\left(  t\right)  =B_{n}e^{-n^{2}t}
$$
Where $B_{n}$ is constant of integration. Hence from (2)
\begin{align*}
v\left(  x,t\right)   &  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi
_{n}\left(  x\right)  \\
&  =A_{0}\left(  t\right)  +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\left(  t\right)  \Phi
_{n}\left(  x\right)  \\
&  =-\frac{2}{\pi}t+B_{0}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}e^{-n^{2}t}\cos\left(
nx\right)
\end{align*}
Since $u=v\left(  x,t\right)  +r\left(  x\right)  $ then the solution becomes
\begin{equation}
u\left(  x,t\right)  =\left(  x-\frac{1}{\pi}x^{2}\right)  -\frac{2}{\pi
}t+B_{0}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}e^{-n^{2}t}\cos\left(  nx\right)  \tag{4}
\end{equation}
At $t=0$
\begin{equation}
\sin\left(  x\right)  =\left(  x-\frac{1}{\pi}x^{2}\right)  +B_{0}+\sum
_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}\cos\left(  nx\right)  \tag{5}
\end{equation}
case $n=0$
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\left(  x\right)  \cos\left(  \sqrt{\lambda_{0}}x\right)
dx=\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(  x-\frac{1}{\pi}x^{2}\right)  \cos\left(
\sqrt{\lambda_{0}}x\right)  dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}B_{0}\cos\left(  \sqrt
{\lambda_{0}}x\right)  dx
$$
But $\lambda_{0}=0$ hence
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\left(  x\right)  dx &  =\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(  x-\frac
{1}{\pi}x^{2}\right)  dx+\int_{0}^{\pi}B_{0}dx\\
2 &  =\frac{\pi^{2}}{6}+B_{0}\pi\\
B_{0} &  =\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{\pi}{6}
\end{align*}
For $n>0$, Multiplying both sides of (5) by $\cos\left(  mx\right)  $ and
integrating
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin\left(  x\right)  \cos\left(  mx\right)  dx=\int_{0}^{\pi
}\left(  x-\frac{1}{\pi}x^{2}\right)  \cos\left(  mx\right)  dx+\sum
_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos\left(  nx\right)  \cos\left(
mx\right)  dx
$$
For $m=1$
\begin{align*}
0 &  =0+B_{1}\frac{\pi}{2}\\
B_{1} &  =0
\end{align*}
For $m>1$
\begin{align*}
-\frac{1+\left(  -1\right)  ^{m}}{m^{2}\left(  -1+m^{2}\right)  } &
=\frac{\pi}{2}B_{m}\\
B_{m} &  =\frac{-2}{\pi}\left(  \frac{1}{m^{2}}\frac{\left(  -1\right)
^{m}+1}{m^{2}-1}\right)
\end{align*}
Hence solution (4) becomes
\begin{align*}
u\left(  x,t\right)   &  =\left(  x-\frac{1}{\pi}x^{2}\right)  -\frac{2}{\pi
}t-\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{2}{\pi}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}e^{-n^{2}t}\cos\left(
nx\right)  \\
u\left(  x,t\right)   &  =\left(  x-\frac{1}{\pi}x^{2}\right)  -\frac{2}{\pi
}t-\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{2}{\pi}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{-2}{\pi}\left(
\frac{1}{n^{2}}\frac{\left(  -1\right)  ^{n}+1}{n^{2}-1}\right)  e^{-n^{2}
t}\cos\left(  nx\right)
\end{align*}

Maple solution verified:

```
heqn := diff(u(x, t), t) = diff(u(x, t), x$2):
ic := u(x, 0) = sin(x):
bc := eval(diff(u(x,t),x),x=0)=1,  eval( diff(u(x,t),x),x=Pi)=-1:
sol := pdsolve({heqn, ic, bc}, u(x, t))
```

[image]

Verification of hand solution (used 10 terms in sum, good enough):

```
mysol=(x-1/Pi x^2)-2/Pi t-Pi/6+2/Pi-2/Pi 
           Sum[((-1)^n+1)/(n^2(n^2-1)) Cos[n x]Exp[-n^2 t],{n,2,10}];
D[mysol,x]/.t->0/.x->0
(*1*)
D[mysol,x]/.t->0/.x->Pi
(*-1*)
Plot[{mysol/.t->0},{x,0,Pi},AxesOrigin->{0,0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Animation of hand solution

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[mysol /. t -> time], {x, 0, Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, {-0.5, 1}}],
 {{time, 0, "time"}, 0, 1, .1},
 TrackedSymbols :> {time},
 Initialization :> {mysol = (x - 1/Pi x^2) - 2/Pi t - Pi/6 + 2/Pi - 
     2/Pi Sum[((-1)^n + 1)/(n^2 (n^2 - 1)) Cos[n x] Exp[-n^2 t], {n, 2, 
         10}]}
 ]
```

[image]

ref (1): [boundary_values](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/boundary_values/report.htm#x1-70001.5)

Comment: 1++,Great answer .

Comment: Changing the coefficient of t is not the same as adding any number to the solution.  And indeed, changing that coefficient does not effect the bc's or ic's, but it breaks the pde.

Comment: The premise that only having neumann boundary conditions makes the solution non-unique does not apply to the heat equation.  There are numerous examples  all over the web.  One is found at http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/rdaileda/teach/s12/m3357/lectures/lecture_3_6_short.pdf.  For some pde's the premise is correct, but different pde's have different bc requirements.  By the way, separation of variables works very well in this case, but you do have to use plus separation as well as times separation to get all the pieces.

Comment: The B1 must be zero. How it is 2/Pi?!

Comment: @Nasser Thank You. But using Mathematica for Fourier series coefficient: FourierCosCoefficient[Sin[x] - (x - ((x^2)/Pi)), x, 0] gets: 4/Pi - Pi/3 which is twice as yours: 2/Pi-P/6 why?

Comment: @Nasser When using [0 , Pi] interval in integrating, there should be a 2 factor because we changed [-Pi, Pi] to [0, Pi] so the Mathematica is right. I don't know why you didn't used the 2 factor.

Comment: 2++,Great answer .

Answer (score 7):

```
 MAPLESOL = (x - 1/Pi x^2) - 2/Pi t - Pi/6 + 2/Pi - 2/Pi Inactivate[
 Sum[((-1)^n + 1)/(n^2 (n^2 - 1)) Cos[n x] Exp[-n^2 t], {n, 2, Infinity}]];

 Plot3D[MAPLESOL /. Infinity -> 20 // Activate, {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

Check equation,initial and boundary conditions:

```
 (D[MAPLESOL /. Infinity -> 20, t] == D[MAPLESOL /. Infinity -> 20, {x, 2}]) // Activate
 (*True*)

 D[MAPLESOL /. Infinity -> 20 // Activate, x] /. t -> 0 /. x -> 0
 (* 1 *)
 D[MAPLESOL /. Infinity -> 20 // Activate, x] /. t -> 0 /. x -> Pi
 (* -1 *)

 Plot[{Sin[x], Evaluate[(MAPLESOL /. Infinity -> 20 // Activate) /. t -> 0]}, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Black}}]

 Plot3D[D[MAPLESOL /. Infinity -> 20 // Activate, x] // Evaluate, {x, 0, Pi}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

It's seems symbolic solution by **Maple** is **OK.**

[image]

Comment: good answer. Yes, this seems like a valid solution. But it is not unique solution as adding any number to the solution is also a solution. `D[(10 + MAPLESOL) /. Infinity -> 20 // Activate, x] /. t -> 0 /. 
 x -> 0` gives `1` as well. May be Mathematica did not solve it because of this? I do not know. Maple 2018 generally can solve more PDE's than Mathematica 11.3

Comment: Adding a constant to the stated solution will break the ic `u[x,0] = Sin[x]`.  I think that the given ic is enough to make the solution unique.When you work the solution with separation of variables there are no extra constants lying around.

Comment: @Nasser and Mariusz …This solution is incorrect, just compare it to the numeric solution.

Answer (score 6):

This question is strongly related to, if not a duplicate of [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/179608/1871). It can be solved with the help of [finite Fourier cosine transform and its inversion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155817/1871):

```
heqn = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
ic = u[x, 0] == Sin[x];
bc = {Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 1, Derivative[1, 0][u][Pi, t] == -1};

help[index_] := 
 Module[{tset = 
    finiteFourierCosTransform[{heqn, ic}, {x, 0, Pi}, index] /. Rule @@@ bc /. 
     HoldPattern@finiteFourierCosTransform[f_, __] :> f}, 
  tsol = DSolve[tset, u[x, t], t][[1, 1, -1]]]
    
tsolgeneral = help[n] // Simplify

tsolzero = help[0]

tsolfunc[n_] = Piecewise[{{tsolgeneral, n != 0}}, tsolzero]

sol = inverseFiniteFourierCosTransform[tsolfunc[n], n, {x, 0, Pi}]

sol = sol /. HoldForm@Sum[expr_, {n, C}] :> sum[Simplify[expr, n > 1], {n, 2, C}] /. 
 sum -> (HoldForm@Sum@## &)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice finite Fourier cosine transform for $n=0$ has been calculated separately because currently `finiteFourierCosTransform`, which is built on `Integrate`, isn't strong enough to obtain the complete solution for general `n`.

Finally let's compare the solution to the numeric one:

```
solapprox = Compile[{t, x}, #] &[sol /. C -> 10 // ReleaseHold];

solnum = NDSolveValue[{heqn, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, Pi}]

Manipulate[Plot[{solnum[x, t], solapprox[t, x]}, {x, 0, Pi}], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

---

## Addendum

The solution found above looks different from the one found by method of separation of variables shown in other answers, but it's possible to prove they're identical i.e.

```
sol= -((2 (-1 + t))/Pi) + (2 
    HoldForm[Sum[-(((1 + (-1)^n) (1 + E^(n^2 t) (-1 + n^2)) 
           Cos[n x])/(E^(n^2 t) (n^2 (-1 + n^2)))), {n, 2, C}]])/Pi
```

is equivalent to

```
mysol=(x-1/Pi x^2)-2/Pi t-Pi/6+2/Pi-
   2/Pi Inactivate[Sum[((-1)^n+1)/(n^2(n^2-1)) Cos[n x]Exp[-n^2 t],{n,2,Infinity}]];
```

We first find the difference between the summand and calculate the sum:

```
summandseparate = (((-1)^n + 1) Cos[n x] Exp[-n^2 t])/(n^2 (n^2 - 1));

summandtransform = ((1 + (-1)^n) E^(-n^2 t) (1 + E^(n^2 t) (-1 + n^2)) Cos[n x])/(
  n^2 (-1 + n^2));

diff = Sum[summandseparate - summandtransform, {n, 2, Infinity}] // FullSimplify
(* 1/4 (-PolyLog[2, E^(-2 I x)] - PolyLog[2, E^(2 I x)]) *)
```

> **Remark**
>
> At least in *v11.2*, you need to modify definition of `diff` to
>
> ```
> diff = Sum[summandseparate - summandtransform // Simplify // Evaluate, {n, 2, Infinity}]
> ```
>
> or the calculation will be extremely slow.

Then the problem boils down to proving the following identity:

```
eq = (x - x^2/π) - (2 t)/π - π/6 + 2/π - 2/Pi diff2 == -((
    2 (-1 + t))/π);
    
-4 diff == -4 diff2 /. First@Solve[eq, diff2]
(* PolyLog[2, E^(-2 I x)] + PolyLog[2, E^(2 I x)] == 1/3 (π^2 - 6 π x + 6 x^2) *)
```

<strike>which seems to be beyond the reach of *Mathematica*, so I asked it in math.SE and get the solution by hand in 6 minutes. Please check [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3079253/58219) for more details.</strike> This identity can be proved using [`ReducePiecewise`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113423/1871):

```
$Assumptions = 0 < x < Pi;

ReducePiecewise[
 FullSimplify@
  PiecewiseExpand@
   PowerExpand@
    FunctionExpand[PolyLog[2, E^(-2 I x)] + PolyLog[2, E^(2 I x)]], x, $Assumptions]
(* 1/3 (π^2 - 6 π x + 6 x^2) *)

$Assumptions =.;
```

Comment: `-4 Series[diff, {x, 0, 10}] // FullSimplify[#, 0 < x < \[Pi]] &` gives you what you want.  I guess your tails are harder to get rid of because your series converges much more slowly than the others because your `Exp[-n^2 t]` only damps out part of the sum while the sum damps out very rapidly in the separate variable case.  I still don't understand why I can't prove your solution satisfies the pde.  Probably need to know a closed form for the whole sum to do that.

Comment: @Bill Yeah _Mathematica_ can verify the identity in [experimental mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_mathematics) style. We can prove the solution satisfy the PDE in the same manner as shown in **Addendum**, the key point is to sum part of the summand, the following code takes about 100 seconds: `terms = List @@ sol /. HoldForm@Sum[a_, _] :> Sequence@a;

sum = Sum[#, {n, 2, Infinity}] &;

{Simplify@D[terms, t], {#, sum /@ Expand@#2} & @@ D[terms, x, x] // 
   Simplify} // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: See my update.  We don't need the math guys for this.

Comment: @BillWatts I find a simpler way to prove the identity, see my update.

Comment: Nice, but I get the same result with `PowerExpand@
  FunctionExpand[
   PolyLog[2, E^(-2 I x)] + PolyLog[2, E^(2 I x)]] // Simplify`.  I don't know what the `Piecewise` functions are doing.

Comment: @BillWatts This is a non rigorous approach, and mine involving `$Assumption` is rigorous. You can check the last link in my answer for detailed discussion.

Answer (score 2):

And yet another way.

```
pde = D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}]

ic = u[x, 0] == Sin[x]

bc = {Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 1, Derivative[1, 0][u][Pi, t] == -1}
```

Separate variables, first with times separation.

```
u[x_, t_] = X[x] T[t]

pde/u[x, t] // Expand
T'[t]/T[t] == X''[x]/X[x]
```

Each side must be equal to a constant.  First try 0.

```
t0eq = T'[t]/T[t] == 0;

DSolve[t0eq, T[t], t] // Flatten
(*{T[t] -> C[1]}*)

t0 = 1
```

since we will combine with constants from the x equation.

```
x0eq = X''[x]/X[x] == 0

DSolve[x0eq, X[x], x] // Flatten
(*{X[x] -> C[2] x + C[1]}*)

x0 = X[x] /. % /. {C[1] -> c1, C[2] -> c2}
```

Now use a negative constant.

```
t1eq = T'[t]/T[t] == -α^2

DSolve[t1eq, T[t], t] // Flatten
(*{T[t] -> C[1] E^(α^2 (-t))}*)

t1 = T[t] /. % /. C[1] -> 1

x1eq = X''[x]/X[x] == -α^2

DSolve[x1eq, X[x], x] // Flatten
(*{X[x] -> C[2] Sin[α x] + C[1] Cos[α x]}*)

x1 = X[x] /. % /. {C[1] -> c3, C[2] -> c4}
```

We don't have all the necessary pieces yet, so do plus separation.

```
u[x_, t_] = X[x] + T[t]

pde
(*T'[t] == X''[x]*)
```

Again, each side must be equal to a constant.  Call it δ.

```
xpeq = X''[x] == δ

DSolve[xpeq, X[x], x] // Flatten
(*{X[x] -> C[2] x + C[1] + (δ x^2)/2}*)

xp = X[x] /. % /. {C[1] -> c5, C[2] -> c6}

tpeq = T'[t] == δ

DSolve[tpeq, T[t], t] // Flatten
(*{T[t] -> C[1] + δ t}*)

tp = T[t] /. % /. C[1] -> 0
```

Put all the pieces together.

```
Clear[c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, α, δ]

u[x_, t_] = x0 t0 + x1 t1 + xp + tp
(*c1 + c2 x + E^(α^2 (-t)) (c3 Cos[α x] + c4 Sin[α x]) + c5 + 
 c6 x + δ t + (δ x^2)/2*)
```

c1 and c5 can be combined, c2 and c6 can be combined.

```
c5 = 0;
c6 = 0;
```

Look at the first bc

```
bc[[1]]
(*c2 + α c4 E^(α^2 (-t)) == 1*)
```

from which we can say

```
c2 = 1;
c4 = 0;
```

and the next bc.

```
bc[[2]]
-(α c3 Sin[π α] E^(α^2 (-t))) + π δ + 1 == -1
```

Make the Sin 0

Solve[α π == n π, α] // Flatten

from which

```
α = n;
$Assumptions = n ∈ Integers && n >= 0
```

Use the rest of the equation to solve for δ

```
c26eq2 = π δ + 1 == -1

δ = δ /. Solve[π δ + 1 == -1, δ][[1]]
```

So far we have

```
u[x, t]
c1 + c3 E^(-n^2 t) Cos[n x] - (2 t)/π - x^2/π + x
```

Now for the ic.

```
ic
(*c1 + c3 Cos[n x] - x^2/π + x == Sin[x]*)
```

We are going to have an infinite series for `n` and the `n=0` will be a constant term.  Since we don't need two of them we can throw out c1.

```
c1 = 0

ic - (-(x^2/π) + x)
(*c3 Cos[n x] == x^2/π - x + Sin[x]*)
```

To solve for `c3`, multiply by `Cos[n x]` and integrate.

```
c3*Integrate[Cos[n*x]^2, {x, 0, Pi}] == (1/Pi)*Integrate[x^2*Cos[n*x], {x, 0, Pi}] - 
   Integrate[x*Cos[n*x], {x, 0, Pi}] + Integrate[Sin[x]*Cos[n*x], {x, 0, Pi}]

c3 = c3 /. Solve[%, c3][[1]] // Simplify
(*-((2 ((-1)^n + 1))/(\[Pi] n^2 (n^2 - 1)))*)
```

The constant term for `n = 0` needs to be done separately.

```
c30*Integrate[1, {x, 0, Pi}] == (1/Pi)*Integrate[x^2*1, {x, 0, Pi}] - 
   Integrate[x*1, {x, 0, Pi}] + Integrate[Sin[x]*1, {x, 0, Pi}]

c30 = c30 /. Solve[%, c30][[1]] // Expand
2/π-π/6
```

Without the sum on n we have

```
u[x_, t_] = u[x, t] + c30
-((2 ((-1)^n + 1) E^(-n^2 t) Cos[n x])/(π n^2 (n^2 - 1))) - (
 2 t)/π - x^2/π + x - π/6 + 2/π
```

Check against the pde.

```
pde
(*True*)
```

We can see that odd n the terms are zero, so change to.

```
-((2 ((-1)^n + 1) E^(-n^2 t) Cos[n x])/(π n^2 (n^2 - 1))) /. 
  n -> 2 n // Simplify
(*-((E^(-4 n^2 t) Cos[2 n x])/(π n^2 (4 n^2 - 1)))*)
```

We have an infinite series of n starting from 1, but lets make a finite series.

```
u[x_, t_, mm_] := 2/Pi - Pi/6 - (2*t)/Pi - x^2/Pi + x - 
   (1/Pi)*Sum[Cos[2*n*x]/(E^(4*n^2*t)*(n^2*(4*n^2 - 1))), {n, 1, mm}]
```

Check against xzczd's numerical solution.

```
gifs = Table[
   Plot[{u[x, t, 20], solnum[x, t]}, {x, 0, π}, 
    PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], {t, 0, 1, .01}];
ListAnimate[%]
```

This solution matches Maple's and Nasser's solution and the numerical solution.  I could not get xzczd's analytic solution to satisfy the pde, which is I think is the cause for the little tails at the end points.

[image]

**Update** on showing the equivalence in the separate variable solution and xzczd's fourier transform  solution.  The separate variable solution simplified by letting the original n go to 2n to eliminate the odd n zero's:

```
usep[x_, t_] := -((2*(t - 1))/Pi) - Pi/6 - x^2/Pi + x - 
   (1/Pi)*Sum[Cos[2*n*x]/(E^(4*n^2*t)*(n^2*(4*n^2 - 1))), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

Rewrite as

```
usep[x, t] := 2/Pi - (2*t)/Pi - (1/Pi)*Sum[Cos[2*n*x]/(E^(4*n^2*t)*(n^2*(4*n^2 - 1))), 
     {n, 1, Infinity}] + Sum[An*Cos[2*n*x], {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

where we find a series such that for `0 <= x <= π`

```
x - x^2/Pi - Pi/6 == Sum[An*Cos[2*n*x], {n, 1, Infinity}];
```

Find `An` by multiplying by `Cos[2 n x]` and integrating.

```
Integrate[(x - x^2/Pi - Pi/6)*Cos[2*n*x], {x, 0, Pi}] == 
  An*Integrate[Cos[2*n*x]^2, {x, 0, Pi}]

An = An /. Solve[%, An][[1]] 
(*-(1/(π n^2))*)
```

Add to the existing sum

```
-(1/π) (E^(-4 n^2 t) Cos[2 n x])/(n^2 (4 n^2 - 1)) + 
  An Cos[2 n x] // Simplify
(*((E^(-4 n^2 t)/(1 - 4 n^2) - 1) Cos[2 n x])/(π n^2)*)
```

And we end up with the same solution as the fourier series solution.

Comment: There're little tails at the end points in the graphic of `solapprox` because I've truncated the summation at $n=10$ (`C -> 10`). If e.g. `C -> 60` is used, the tails will be almost invisible. And, it's possible to prove my solution is identical to the one found by method of separation of variables, see my update.