# DSolve returns no result

Tags: differential-equations

I'd like to solve a partial differential equation on a infinite strip. My code is the following:

```
eqn = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] + 2 D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] + u[x, t] == 
   D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
bc = {Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0][u][2 π, t] == 0};
ic = {u[x, 0] == Cos[x], Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == Abs[Cos[x/2]]};
Ω = Rectangle[{0, 2 π}, {0, Infinity}];
DSolve[{eqn, bc, ic}, u[x, t], {x, t} ∈ Ω]
```

Mathematica returns no result -- what could have possible gone wrong?

Comment: `Rectangle[{0, 2 \[Pi]}, {0, Infinity}]` makes no sense for Mathematica. In particular, `Graphics[Rectangle[{0, 2 \[Pi]}, {0, Infinity}]]` produces an error message.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/189706/1871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Infinity` does not work with `Rectangle`. A proper definition can just use Reals instead of `Infinity` with Elements. `Rectangle` is not needed, used by Wolfram Inc. for that purpose.

DSolve has on itself an options section for domains.

As shown in the Basic Example for [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) it is preferable to solve for a pure function `u` instead of a function `u[x,t]`.

A simple check of the boundary and initial conditions shows, they are inconsistent. The initial condition are inconsistent too. Derivative[0,1] is the derivative to time. It is set to a time-independent function in x with frequency one half.

```
eqn = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] + 2 D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] + u[x, t] == 
   D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
bc = {Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0][u][2 π, t] == 0};
ic = {u[x, 0] == Cos[x], Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == Abs[Cos[x/2]]};
ndsol = NDSolve[{eqn, bc, ic}, u, {x, 0, 2 π}, {t, 0, 4.5}]
```

Mathematica does solve this with the message `NDSolve::ibcinc`.
[image: error message]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. First@%63], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 4.5}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Graphics representation]

Boundary conditions are matched well:

```
bc[[All, 1]] /. t -> 0 /. First@ndsol
```

(*    {-0.000171153, 0.000171153} *)

The boundary values are constant the value for all time.

Initial conditions too:

```
ic[[All, 1]] /. x -> 0 /. First@ndsol
{1., 1.}
```

The solution prefers one over the other initial condition on the complete domain.

For example if all bc and is conditions are set to zero, then the message disappears.

Everything is OK with the ic and bc for the solution and it looks:

[image: Graphics]

If it is not possible to get on other paths to the correct bc and ic. Fit them to the general solution of the partial differential equation.

Comment: In this case the `ibcinc` warning is caused by the sparse spatial grid. Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20771/1871 And Akku14 has shown another way to adjust the grid size in [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/221418/1871).

Answer (score 4):

`DSolve` (version 8.0) can't find a solution. Do it numerically.

```
ndsol = NDSolve[{eqn, bc, ic}, u, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   MaxStepSize -> {5*10^-3, 10^-2}, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 5]

Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, t] /. First@ndsol], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Test

```
bc[[All, 1]] /. t -> 0 /. First@ndsol

(*   {-5.1341*10^-13, 5.23173*10^-13}   *)

ic[[All, 1]] /. x -> 0 /. First@ndsol

(*   {1., 1.}   *)

Plot3D[Evaluate@Chop[eqn[[1]] - eqn[[2]] /. First@ndsol], 
{x, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> 10^-5]
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to make the grid that dense, `MaxStepSize -> {0.2, Automatic}` is enough.

Answer (score 3):

Though `DSolve` can't handle the problem at the moment, the symbolic solution can be found with the help of [finite Fourier cosine transform and its inversion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155817/1871):

```
eqn = D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] + 2 D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] + u[x, t] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];
bc = {Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][u][2 π, t] == 0};
ic = {u[x, 0] == Cos[x], 
   Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 
    Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand[Abs[Cos[x/2]], Reals]};

(* Definition of finiteFourierCosTransform isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
tsetlst = Assuming[{n > 0 && n != 2}, 
      Simplify@finiteFourierCosTransform[{eqn, ic}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, #]] /. 
     Rule @@@ bc & /@ {0, 2, n} /. HoldPattern@finiteFourierCosTransform[a_, __] :> a

tsollst = u[x, t] /. First@DSolve[#, u[x, t], t] & /@ tsetlst

tsol = Piecewise[{tsollst // Most, {n == 0, n == 2}} // Transpose, tsollst // Last] // 
  FullSimplify

mid = inverseFiniteFourierCosTransform[tsol, n, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]

sol = (mid[[2]] /. {n, C} -> {n, 2, 2} // ReleaseHold) + mid /. {{n, C} -> {n, 3, C}, 
   HoldPattern@Piecewise[_, a_] :> a}
```

> $$u(x,t) = \frac{2 e^{-t} t}{\pi }+\frac{e^{-t} \cos (x) (4 \sin (t)+3 \pi  (\sin (t)+\cos (t)))}{3 \pi }+\sum _{n=3}^\infty \frac{\cos \left(\frac{n x}{2}\right) \left(8 \cos \left(\frac{n \pi }{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{n t}{2}\right) (\sinh (t)-\cosh (t) )\right)}{n \left(n^2-1 \right) \pi}$$

Let's compare it with the numeric solution:

```
testfunc = Function[{x, t}, #] &[sol /. C -> 30 // ReleaseHold];

mol[n_Integer, o_: "Pseudospectral"] := {"MethodOfLines", 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> n, 
    "MinPoints" -> n, "DifferenceOrder" -> o}}

nsol = NDSolveValue[{eqn, ic, bc}, u, {t, 0, 4}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Method -> mol[50, 4]];

Manipulate[Plot[{testfunc[x, t], nsol[x, t]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> 1, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Red, Thick, Dashed}}], {t, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

## Remark

1. `Abs` is transformed to `UnitStep` so `DSolve` can solve faster.
2. Finite Fourier cosine transform for $n=0$ and $n=2$ cases have been calculated separately because currently `finiteFourierCosTransform`, which is built on `Integrate`, can't handle these two special cases properly when they're hidden behind the symbolic `n`.
3. `sol` is just a simplified version of `mid`.