# Sum of Fourier Sine Series Not Giving Original Function

Tags: summation, series-expansion, fourier-analysis

When I plug the below sum (from [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/FourierSineSeries.aspx)) into Mathematica 12.1.1, why do I get something different from the original function ($1 + x^2$)?

[image]

```
S = HoldForm[Sum[2/(n*Pi)^3*((2 L^2 - n^2*Pi^2*(1 + L^2))*(-1)^n - 2*L^2 + n^2*Pi^2)*Sin[n*Pi*x/L], {n, 1, Infinity}]]

FullSimplify[ReleaseHold[S], Assumptions -> 0 <= x <= L]
```

[image]

Comment: The code `L = 5; S = 
 HoldForm[Sum[
   2/(n*Pi)^3*((2 L^2 - n^2*Pi^2*(1 + L^2))*(-1)^n - 2*L^2 + 
      n^2*Pi^2)*Sin[n*Pi*x/L], {n, 1, Infinity}]];

FullSimplify[ReleaseHold[S], Assumptions -> 0 <= x <= L];` `Plot[% - x^2 - 1, {x, 0, L}]` works well in version12.0. The result of `FullSimplify` differs from yours.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, the plot shows 0, but is there a way to get the original expression?

Comment: My best is `L=5;s = Sum[2/(n*Pi)^3*((2 L^2 - n^2*Pi^2*(1 + L^2))*(-1)^n - 2*L^2 + 
     n^2*Pi^2)*Sin[n*Pi*x/L], {n, 1, Infinity}];` `FullSimplify[D[s , {x, 3}], Assumptions -> x >= 0 && x <= L]` which performs `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Find the function $f(x)$ by using its fourier expansion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113407/find-the-function-fx-by-using-its-fourier-expansion), it looks like it is usually not possible to get $f(x)$ from the infinite series.

Comment: Unfortunately, `PowerExpand[  FunctionExpand[-(1/\[Pi]^3)      I (-\[Pi]^2 Log[1 - E^(I \[Pi] x)] + \[Pi]^2 Log[        E^(-I \[Pi] x) (-1 + E^(I \[Pi] x))] +       2 \[Pi]^2 Log[1 + E^(I \[Pi] x)] -       2 \[Pi]^2 Log[E^(-I \[Pi] x) (1 + E^(I \[Pi] x))] -       2 PolyLog[3, -E^(-I \[Pi] x)] + 2 PolyLog[3, E^(-I \[Pi] x)] +       2 PolyLog[3, -E^(I \[Pi] x)] - 2 PolyLog[3, E^(I \[Pi] x)])]]` does not work